# How to triplicate each sentence in each paragragh in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to triplicate (copy and paste) each sentence in each paragraph in ms word document, i have come up with the below code but it doesnt exit loop and runs till word crushes. Any alternative or improvements?

````vb
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph
    
     For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
         
       Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdSentence, count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

Selection.Copy
      
     Selection.EndOf
     
     Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    
    Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
  
     Next

End Sub
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact you need to loop backwards through the document, you need to understand that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following:

*Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.*

For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

With that in mind, try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
  For i = .Sentences.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Sentences(i)
      If Len(Trim(.Text)) > 1 Then
        If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
          If (.End >= .Cells(1).Range.End) Then
            .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
            .Characters.Last.InsertBefore " "
            .End = .End - 1
          End If
        ElseIf .Characters.Last Like "[" & Chr(9) & "-" & Chr(13) & "]" Then
          .Characters.Last.InsertBefore " "
          .End = .End - 1
        End If
        Set Rng = .Duplicate
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Rng.FormattedText = .FormattedText
        Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Rng.FormattedText = .FormattedText
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It works but fails in a document with tables. MS word says that "A table in this document has become corrupted."

Comment: I don't see any mention of tables in your original post - or any attempt to deal with them in your own code. Try the revised code.

Comment: The revised code I get the error "Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells." with some tables. it works with some other tables. Is there a way to make it work with vertically merged cells?

Comment: How about investing some effort of your own! First you fail to mention anything about the document having tables, then, having recognised that was an issue, you didn't bother mentioning that the tables might have vertically merged cells. I've already done almost all of the work for you.